# How to rotate camera around player in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to rotate the camera around my player gameobject while holding the left mouse button. How would I approach this?

Also, I've read a bit on Vector 3, but I don't have a full understanding of it. Anybody who could explain it would be greatly appreciated.

I've looked at youtube videos and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcn7hz7J7sI) is exactly the concept I was looking for. I  was just having trouble applying it to my code.

I'm on a bit of a time crunch, exams are nearing and my teacher hasn't explained most things that are explained in the video.

// This is my code inside the camera which follows the ball/player

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptBallCam : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject player;

private Vector3 offset;

void Start()
{
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
}
```

//End of code inside camera

//Code inside of player/ball

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptBall : MonoBehaviour
{



public float speed;



private Rigidbody rb;





void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
}
```

// end code

Results I'm expecting are exactly shown at 1:22 in

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcn7hz7J7sI

Comment: If you look that last video just seconds before the 1:22 its showing some code on how to resolve your issue, its the quaternion thing

Comment: By "don't have a full understanding of [Vector3]" I'm assuming you mean vectors in general. It would be well worth your time to learn a bit about vector operations. They are phenomenally useful (I may be biased -- I studied mechanical engineering). I use `Transform.RotateAround` in my project to orbit around a point. It handles all the transformations for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. The script goes on your camera.

Basically this script works by first getting the direction your mouse has moved in. In this case the X axis `Mouse X` (left/right direction). Then we take our rotation speed `turnSpeed`, and use it to rotate around the player by that amount of degrees using [Quaternion.AngleAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html). Finally we make sure that the camera is always looking at the player by using `transform.LookAt`

```
 using UnityEngine;  
 using System.Collections;    

public class OrbitPlayer : MonoBehaviour {

     public float turnSpeed = 5.0f;
     public GameObject player;

     private Transform playerTransform;     
     private Vector3 offset;
     private float yOffset = 10.0f;
     private float zOffset = 10.0f;

     void Start () {
         playerTransform = player.transform;
         offset = new Vector3(playerTransform.position.x, playerTransform.position.y + yOffset, playerTransform.position.z + zOffset);
     }

     void FixedUpdate()
     {
         offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis (Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
         transform.position = playerTransform.position + offset; 
         transform.LookAt(playerTransform.position);
     }  
}
```

There is a lot of information on this topic over here:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/600577/camera-rotation-around-player-while-following.html